# Logspout support for sending logs to Logstash via TCP

Tags: logstash

I have an requirement for sending container logs to Logstash server via tcp using logspout. I have been able to do this via UDP but TCP is required.

Can anyone point out to a repository which has TCP support for Logstash, or steps that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to tell logspout to do this by providing "syslog+tcp" instead of just "syslog" in your URL:

```
docker run --name logspout -d --env DEBUG=1 \
  --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --publish=127.0.0.1:8000:80 \
  gliderlabs/logspout:latest \
  syslog+tcp://<syslog host>:514
```

The "--env DEBUG=1" of course turns on some additional debug messages, and "--publish=127.0.0.1:8000:80" means that you can tail the logs that logspout has received in real time using

```
 curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/logs
```